# DCEVM and Eclipse breakpoint issue

Tags: eclipse, dcevm

I'm using the latest DCEVM on win7, Eclipse Luna, jdk1.8.0_51 from Oracle to run tomcat in debug mode. Tomcat gets started from a separate console, not from within eclipse. DCEVM applies my code changes but than my breakpoints in the modified class do not work anymore. I have to restart Tomcat.
Ideas?